# Get Android OS version of device connected via ADB

Tags: android, shell, adb

Can one use `adb` or `adb shell` commands to get attached emulator/device OS info, i.e. API version?

Answer (score 290, accepted):

To get Android version you can use:

```
adb shell getprop ro.build.version.release
```

To get API level:

```
adb shell getprop ro.build.version.sdk
```

You can see all available properties with this command:

```
adb shell getprop
```

Comment: If you have more devices attached to your machine, you will not be able to use this command by default. You need to provide ANDROID_SERIAL environment variable which identifies your device ID. This is an example:
adb devices (you will get attached device IDs)
ANDROID_SERIAL=DEVICE_ID adb shell getprop ro.build.version.release

Comment: If you have several devices connected, specify `-s ID` where ID is the device's ID from `adb devices`. For example `adb -s 1234 shell getprop ro.build.version.release `

Answer (score 19):

I know , you already got the correct solution , & here is my solution only for additional information.

You will get every details by `cat` ing the `/system/build.prop` file like

```
adb shell cat /system/build.prop
```

[Here is collection of adb commands](http://codeadapter.blogspot.in/2014/10/adb-commands.html)

Comment: I had to use this `adb shell cat system/build.prop`. `cd`ing didn't work for me.

Comment: Now it is adb shell cat /system/build.prop. But this will not work for user device. It will work only for rooted device.

Answer (score 13):

For all properties:

```
adb shell getprop
```